# "Ghost" blank activity showing up randomly

Tags: huawei, android-10, emui

For couple of weeks I'm experiencing weird behaviour on my P30 Pro.

Randomly, from time to time, for a split second blank activity window is sliding from the right and back making usage of the phone problematic.
Especially while recording a video what leads the process to stop.
Nothing shows up on the recent apps view, AVG doesn't show any threats. Do you have any idea how can I hunt down responsible app?

Android 10, EMUI 11

Comment: If you enable Developer Options and adb on the device you can execute `adb logcat -b events` on a connected PC with adb minimal or Android SDK installed. This log may give you hints which app is responsible for the window.

Comment: @Robert, you should make it an answer, but expand it.  It is terse for anyone who hasn't used ADB before.

Comment: @RohitGupta My problem is that this is just theoretical knowledge, as I never had such a problem. I do remember a post here in ASE about events logcat and identifying an app, but I am unable to find it.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the tip, it turned out to be samsung apps related to galaxy watch. adjusting autostart / memory cleanup settings for them solved the issue.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer best with original output from your logcat event log. That would be very helpful for others having the same or a similar problem.